# Hadoop + warnings as slow block-receive from data-node machines

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, hadoop, hdfs

We have Hadoop cluster with `487` data-nodes machines ( each data-node machine include also the Service node-manager ) , all machines are physical machines ( DELL ) , and OS is RHEL 7.9 version.

Each data-node machine have 12 disks, each disk is with size of 12T

Hadoop cluster type installed from HDP packages ( previously was under Horton-works and now under Cloudera )

Users are complain about slowness from spark applications that run on data-nodes machines

And after investigation we seen the following warning from data-node logs

```
2024-03-18 17:41:30,230 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 401ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.24:50010, 172.87.171.23:50010]
2024-03-18 17:41:49,795 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 410ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.26:50010, 172.87.171.31:50010]
2024-03-18 18:06:29,585 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 303ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.34:50010, 172.87.171.22:50010]
2024-03-18 18:18:55,931 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 729ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.11.27:50010]
```

from above log we can see the `warning Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took xxms` and also the data-nodes machines as `172.87.171.23,172.87.171.24` etc.

from my understanding the exceptions as Slow `BlockReceiver write packet to mirror` indicate maybe on delay in writing the block to OS cache or disk

So I am trying to collect the reasons for this warning / exceptions , and here there are

1. delay in writing the block to OS cache or disk
2. cluster is as or near its resources limit ( memory , CPU or disk )
3. network issues between machines

From my verification I not see **disk** or **CPU** or **memory** problem , we checked all machines

From network side I not see special issues that relevant to machines itself

And we also used the iperf3 ro check the Bandwidth between one machine to other.

here is example between `data-node01` to `data-node03`  ( from my understanding and please Correct me if I am wrong looks like Bandwidth is ok )

From data-node01

```
iperf3 -i 10 -s

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  7.90 GBytes  6.78 Gbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-20.00  sec  8.21 GBytes  7.05 Gbits/sec
[  5]  20.00-30.00  sec  7.25 GBytes  6.23 Gbits/sec
[  5]  30.00-40.00  sec  7.16 GBytes  6.15 Gbits/sec
[  5]  40.00-50.00  sec  7.08 GBytes  6.08 Gbits/sec
[  5]  50.00-60.00  sec  6.27 GBytes  5.39 Gbits/sec
[  5]  60.00-60.04  sec  35.4 MBytes  7.51 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  43.9 GBytes  6.28 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

From data-node03

```
iperf3 -i 1 -t 60 -c 172.87.171.84

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   792 MBytes  6.64 Gbits/sec    0   3.02 MBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   834 MBytes  6.99 Gbits/sec   54   2.26 MBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   960 MBytes  8.05 Gbits/sec    0   2.49 MBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   896 MBytes  7.52 Gbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   790 MBytes  6.63 Gbits/sec    0   2.70 MBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   838 MBytes  7.03 Gbits/sec    4   1.97 MBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   816 MBytes  6.85 Gbits/sec    0   2.17 MBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   728 MBytes  6.10 Gbits/sec    0   2.37 MBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   692 MBytes  5.81 Gbits/sec   47   1.74 MBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   778 MBytes  6.52 Gbits/sec    0   1.91 MBytes
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   785 MBytes  6.58 Gbits/sec   48   1.57 MBytes
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   861 MBytes  7.23 Gbits/sec    0   1.84 MBytes
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   844 MBytes  7.08 Gbits/sec    0   1.96 MBytes
```

Note - Nic card/s are with `10G` speed ( we checked this by ethtool )

We also checked the firmware-version of the NIC card

```
ethtool -i p1p1
driver: i40e
version: 2.8.20-k
firmware-version: 8.40 0x8000af82 20.5.13
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:3b:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

We also checked from kernel messages ( `dmesg` ) but no seen something special.

from dmesg about CPU

```
dmesg  | grep CPU
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 32 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] smpboot: Ignoring 160 unusable CPUs in ACPI table
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:5120 nr_cpumask_bits:32 nr_cpu_ids:32 nr_node_ids:2
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=32, Nodes=2
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=5120 to nr_cpu_ids=32.
[    0.184771] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
[    0.184943] TAA: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.184944] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.324340] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz (fam: 06, model: 4f, stepping: 01)
[    0.327772] smpboot: CPU 1 Converting physical 0 to logical die 1
[    0.408126] NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.436824] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.436828] TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.
[    0.464933] Brought up 32 CPUs
[    3.223989] acpi LNXCPU:7e: hash matches
[   49.145592] L1TF CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See CVE-2018-3646 and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html for details.
```